# Which edition of sql server 2008,10,12,14 support replication and publication, as i need sync of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

Please help me regarding sync of data between two sql servers automatically using replication and publication. 
Please help me which edition provide these features and how to configure these services to automatically sync data between local sql server and remote sql server.

Thanks

Comment: There's no SQL Server 2010 ..... - 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 - that's it

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.100).aspx You can view the features for 2008R2, 2012 and 2014 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Replication has been part of SQL Server at least since the version 2005.

It's not a question of version number, but of type of edition (express, standard...)

If you need replication, you will need at least a standard version on the publisher server. Any version will work on the subscriber.

Note that if you just want to get a backup (for development purposes or a preprod server), you're probably better off writing a small script (in Powershell for instance) that generates a backup of the source server and downloads/uploads it to the target server every night or so.